# Django problem with creating user then logging them in

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

Hello all you helpful people out there (and goodbye none-helpful people :D ). I'm trying to create a user in django (1.2.4) and then log them in after saving them. My problem is I'm getting NotImplementedError and looking at the traceback it's being raised by django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser . Here is part of my view code:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        p = request.POST
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = UserForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
                # ...
                form.save()
                user=authenticate(username=p['username'],password=p['password'])
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect after POST
```

So it looks to me that It's trying to log in an anymouse user instead of the one I'm authenticating, how can I overcome this?

Thanks
P.S. The users are being created in the database, it just won't log them in using this code.

Traceback:

> Environment:
>        Request Method: POST
>        Request URL: http://localhost:8000/signup/
>        Django Version: 1.2.4
>        Python Version: 2.6.1
>        Installed Applications:
>        ['django.contrib.auth',
>         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>         'django.contrib.sessions',
>         'django.contrib.sites',
>         'django.contrib.messages',
>         'django.contrib.admin',
>         'django.contrib.admindocs',
>         'django_extensions',
>         'REDACTED_APPs',
>        Installed Middleware:
>        ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>         'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
>         'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>         'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>         'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>         'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware')

```
 Traceback:    
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response    
   100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)    
 File "REDACTED/views.py" in signup    
   19.                 login(request,user)    
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login    
   71.     user.save()    
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in save    
   430.         raise NotImplementedError    

 Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /signup/    
 Exception Value:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I think is happening here is `authenticate` is returning `None`, therefore `login` is using `request.user` (an `AnonymousUser`).

It looks like the information used to create the user is different to what you are passing to `authenticate`. I would double check that the user is being saved correctly (especially the password).

**Edit**: From other answers I see you are using a custom user form. You should use `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`, it's `save()` method will set the password correctly.

*The below doesn't work without manually setting the backend attribute, more trouble than it's worth, left for posterity*

The easy out is to skip the authenticate step here (it doesn't add anything important)

```
user = UserForm.save()
login(request, user)
```

Comment: Partly right, it is returning None. I tried your solution and it dosen't work because without authenticate it dosen't get some backend information apparently according to the docs "Calling authenticate() first
When you're manually logging a user in, you must call authenticate() before you call login(). authenticate() sets an attribute on the User noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the backends documentation for details), and this information is needed later during the login process."

Comment: Thanks, the other answers are good but UserCreationForm is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a user with **form.save()** is not a good way... Because, since passwords are saved in a hashed format, pasword set by using

```
user.passord = password
```

simply writes unhashed data to the database and django auth can not check it correctly... What you need is:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']

user = User.objects.create(username=username)
if password:
    user.set_password(password)
else:
    user.set_unusable_password()
user.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it will help but it's best to extract form fields like the following:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
hashed_password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()

user = authenticate(username=username, password=hashed_password)
if user:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

From the users that have been created with your current code, can you authenticate them into the system?

**Here's an alternate way to create and login using a login form and creating the user manually:**

```
# forms.py
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


# views.py
import hashlib

username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
hashed_password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()

# assuming username is unique
User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, defaults={'password': hashed_password, 'is_active': True})

# If password doesn't work, try hashed_password next
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Tried doing form.cleaned_data get the same original error. Can you elaborate on other ways to authenticate the newly created user? That's what I want to know.

Comment: You are creating and authenticating those users but the code is failing.  With the new user's username and password, can you authenticate into the site or the admin?

Comment: THANKS, now we are getting somewhere! I had only checked to see that they where indead created, but trying to login on the backend I find that it does not authenticate there either. So I look at the password on the backend and find that it doesn't auto encrypt them, so that's probably the issue right there. How should I encrypt the password before saving the userform. At this point I should note that UserForm is a model form I made, if there is a default one what do I need to import to access it?

Comment: I've added an alternative way to create and authenticate, see above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ThierryLam, you have saved my day with this answer, works good

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2 I've used the following code for signup

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(
            user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            # Create the user profile
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'account/register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})
```

Here we can further enhance it by calling Django hashing methods

Following are the django hashing methods:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]
```

We can call the above hashers as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher

class MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    """
    A subclass of PBKDF2PasswordHasher that uses 100 times more iterations.
    """
    iterations = PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations * 100
```

For further hashing new methods like argon2/bcrypt, we need to install argon2.

Please refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/